# Conditions inside init() in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, toggle, init

I need to use init with SwiftUI, but I am just learning about initializers. I have found many complex examples, but I cannot understand the basics.

How to initialize different values inside init() based on value of some other var, for example based on true/false from a toggle?

EXAMPLE CODE

I was trying something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ToggleView: View {
    
    @State var toggleValue: Bool = true
    
    var testValue: String
    
    init() {
        if toggleValue {
            self.testValue = "true"
        } else {
            self.testValue = "false"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: $toggleValue) {
                Text("True or false?")
            }.padding()
            
            Text("Selected value:")
            Text("\(testValue)")
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ToggleView()
    }
}
```

But on line with **if toggleValue {** I am getting an error:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

I have tried changing:

```
var testValue: String

init() {
```

to:

```
@Binding var testValue: String

init(testValue: Binding<String>) {
```

But it doesn't work either. How to bind this testValue with toggle, so after taping on toggle my app would print: "Selected value: false"?

Comment: You don't need a `testValue` at all. Just do `Text("\(toggleValue)")` instead of `Text("\(testValue)")`. In fact, you shouldn't have a second thing that is binded to the toggle, because SwiftUI likes a single source of truth.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to learn about init on this (or another simple example). I have a problem with init with fetchrequest and dynamic filters in one app I am working on. And I cannot move forward without understanding inits tied with Booleans. And optional bools in the next step

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*TLDR; You can never initialise a stored property with another stored property. If you want to initialise two properties with the same value, that value has to come from a parameter in your initialiser or some constant.*

---

The compiler actually gives a very useful error. All stored properties need to be initialised before you can use `self`. In your example you have two stored properties: `toggleValue` and `testValue`. `toggleValue` is initialised, but `testValue` is not. Since reading a stored property is an example of `using self`, you *cannot* use a stored property to initialise another stored property. You *can* initialise properties with parameters in `init()`.

For example:

```
init(initialValue: Bool) {
    testValue = initialValue ? "true" : "false"
}
```

Or you can make testValue a computed property that depends on another property:

```
var testValue: String {
    toggleValue ? "true" : "false"
}
```

If you want to keep `testValue` and `toggleValue` in sync *and* be able to modify testValue you can use a binding:

```
var testValue: Binding<String> { 
    Binding<String>(
        get: { toggleValue ? "true" : "false" },
        set: { toggleValue = $0 == "true" }
    )
}
```

If you only want to initialise testValue *in sync* with toggleValue you can use a static const:

```
static let initialValue = true
@State var toggleValue = ToggleView.initialValue
var testValue = ToggleView.initialValue ? "true" : "false"
```

Or use a constant in the initialiser:

```
init() {
    let initialValue = true
    toggleValue = initialValue
    testValue = initialValue ? "true" : "false"
    // Note that in this case the compiler will inform you the 'false'
    // branch will never be executed (which is correct). To prevent this
    // you can either depend on a static constant, create your own
    // extension on bool to provide a string, or just use:
    // testValue = "\(initialValue)"
}
```

Note that structs have an implicit initialiser with it stored properties listed in order of appearance. With initialised properties as optional parameters. This means you can initialise ToggleView in the following ways (without specifying an initialiser):

```
ToggleView(toggleValue: false, testValue: true)
ToggleView(testValue: true)
```

Comment: With this last example you mean that I can initialize properties from one view to another? Having `ToggleView(testValue: true)` in ContentView, for example? This I know. But I still cannot manage to init in just this view. I have tried `init(initialValue: Bool) {
    testValue = initialValue
}` because testValue should be String, I guess. But when I change it to String I get another error. And should I write initialValue or is it a placeholder for some real value? I tried both, still doesn't work. I think that the problem is my limited understanding of inits :/

Comment: As an answer to your first question yes. I missed testValue was a string, I’ll update the answer. Don’t worry, we all start from somewhere.

Comment: `initialValue` is the name of the parameter. You can use any name you like. It is valid during the scope of init().

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I am getting an error now in SceneDelegate: `Missing argument for parameter 'initialValue' in call`. What I did with my code - I have commented out my `init() {...}` and added your `init`. I understand code there: testValue will be "True" if initialValue is true. But I don't know why it doesn't work and how it is connected with toggle in my example? If it worked, how would changing Toggle change  text in testValue as they are not connected anywhere?

Comment: I see you updated your answer more, Jack. My comment was to previous version. I will read and try more :)

Comment: If you have a parameter in the init of ToggleView, you'll have to provide that parameter when you construct it (e.g. in your SceneDelegate). ToggleView(initialValue: true). If you don't want that choose one of the other options.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to avoid `ToggleView(testValue: true)` here or editing SceneDelegate so I tried an option with  a constant in the initialiser. This gave me error `'self' used before all stored properties are initialized` on line `toggleValue = initialValue`. The error was gone after I changed `var testValue: String` to `var testValue: String = "test"`. But I am still gettin a warning that `testValue = initialValue ? "true" : "false"` in init will never be executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216921/discussion-between-jack-goossen-and-mallow).

Comment: I understand first 2 examples and working on last 2. I have a problem with 3rd example. 'var testValue = Binding<String>(...)' should be inside init or not? And in a ChildView or can I use it all in one view. I cannot make it work. Also, shouldn't it be ) at the end instead of } ?

Comment: Thanks, there were multiple errors in that example. The binding is supposed to be a computed property as well, see the update.